# One of cross validation results is negative in linear regression

Tags: cross-validation

I'm a beginner at using sklearn. When I did 5 folds in cross validation in a linear regression model:

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

lm = LinearRegression()

scores = cross_val_score(lm, X_train, y_train, scoring='r2',cv=5)

The result is array([ 0.64692742, 0.72012611, -1.16363191, 0.68953062, 0.77769532])

It's a linear regression model, the prediction I did r2 score is 0.68. I don't quite understand why one of them is negative, while the others are similar to the prediction results. Is that because my dataset is not large enough?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Please don't repost closed questions: edit them instead.  See our [help] for guidance.

Comment: Please edit your [previous post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/545050/one-of-cross-validation-result-is-negative) to clarify the points that Tim and I raised.